# invoke xterm and run command with variable

Tags: tcsh, xterm

I would like invoke a xterm with two commands where the first command is to echo some header message follow by some other command (for this sample code I use sleep command for simplicity).  The exec command with "echo $msg1" isn't print out any message.  Please help me to fix it.

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set msg1 = ""
set msg1 = "$msg1#[INFO] xx"
set msg1 = "$msg1#[INFO] yy"

# not okay
exec /usr/bin/xterm -e sh -c 'echo "$msg1" | tr "#" "\n" ;sleep 5'
# okay
exec /usr/bin/xterm -e sh -c 'echo hello;sleep 5'
exec /usr/bin/xterm -e sh -c 'echo hello#world | tr "#" "\n" ;sleep 5'
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables don't work inside single quotes (`'`), only double quotes (`"`):

```
% set x = 'asdf'

% echo '$x'
$x

% echo "$x"
asdf
```

Right now, the `sh` process inside the xterm will see `echo "$msg1"`, but it doesn't know about the `$msg1` variable since that's local to the script, which is a different process.

You can adjust that command to something like:

```
exec /usr/bin/xterm -e sh -c "echo '$msg1' | tr '#' '\n' ; sleep 5"
```

But this won't work well if `msg1` can contain single quote or has a `\` at the end. Quoting is complex, especially since you're dealing with two different shells (your script and the `sh` inside xterm) each with its own quoting rules, so it's probably better to use an environment variable:

```
setenv msg1 "$msg1"
```

And then you can use the same command as you had above, since the environment variables are inherited by the child process.